# Why doesn't the marquee stop on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover, marquee

To stop the marquee for mouse-hover I did this:

```
CSS:

<style type="text/css">

.wm {
    border: solid 2px;
    border-color:#0aa2e3;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:13px;
}

marquee:hover {
    animation-play-state:paused;
}

</style>
```

---

```
HTML :

<p class="wm"> <marquee> ... </marquee> </p>
```

But nothing happens as I point my mouse over the moving paragraph. Why is that ?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I thought it would have to do with chrome being a webkit browser, but Kevin seems to have pointed out the real problem below.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using a marquee?

Answer (score 5):

That's because marquee isn't a CSS3 animation and that's about all you can pause via `animation-play-state:paused;`

But more importantly: **You should no longer be using marquee at all**

If you need something similar, like a moving link list that can be clicked and stops on hovering, you should be looking for alternatives, I could bet there are some jQuery news ticker plug-ins out there.

---

**Edit:** Since you're looking for a pauseable CSS3 Animation according to your comments, you'll require the following markup:

```
<p class="marquee"> <!-- the wrapping container -->
  <span> ... </span> <!-- the tray moving around -->
</p>
```

The content in your span will be the one moving around your wrapping container with the `marquee` class.

```
/* define the animation */
@keyframes marquee {
  0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}

/* define your limiting container */
.marquee {
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* this is the tray moving around your container */
.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  text-indent: 0;
  animation: marquee 15s linear infinite; /* here you select the animation */
}

/* pause the animation on mouse over */
.marquee span:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused
}
```

Also as an jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MaY5A/209/

---

Additional note:

Since CSS3 animations are still experimental in some browsers, you might have to add vendor prefixes. Which can be weird especially for the animation definition itself:

```
@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  ...
}

@-moz-keyframes marquee {
  ...
}
```

But `transform`, `translate`, `animation` and `animation-play-state` might require vendor prefixes, depending on how far back you want to support browsers.

Comment: and I am not permitted to use js

Comment: In your fiddle they have added animation for the `span` which is inside the marquee paragraph.

Comment: How can I implement like in the fiddle ?

Comment: The jsfiddle you added doesn't use marquee, but a CSS3 animation substitute, but I'll have to check what's possible here.

Comment: That's odd, it's using pretty much the exact same code as the one you linked. (it's also moving for me)

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your requirement of using CSS3 animations and no javascript.

Comment: @KevinBusse Its not working for chrome. Even after adding `@-webkit-keyframes marquee`

Comment: @KevinBusse Here are the errors for `chrome` http://s14.postimg.org/ttsdxwmgx/Capture.jpg

Comment: The crossed in http://s14.postimg.org/ttsdxwmgx/Capture.jpg say _invalid property value_

Comment: You'll have to use `-webkit-animation` and `-webkit-animation-play-state` if you're using it on your own site, jsfiddle is doing that automatically, but if you want to use it on our onw page, you will handle the vendor prefixes yourself.